# Avoid Bootstrap tab from increasing site height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap tab (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) component on a page which have 2 tab contents and one of them is way longer than the other.

Even if the smaller one is set as **"active"** the page displays a long white space below the tab with the height of the second hidden tab content.

My question is how to make the tab container set its height by the currently active tab. I mean, when looking to the smaller one, the height is set based on it and only if the user select the another one, its height get increased.

Hope the answer is clear. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot, fiddle or sample code?

Comment: add a custom class to the div which shows the data description and then write the "height:auto;" for that class.

Comment: Are you sure you have it implemented correctly? Tabs that are not active are set to 'display:none', which means they are not occupying space. I just checked an implementation of tabs that I did, and the non-active tabs do not behave the way you have described.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. After checking on jsFiddle the tabs worked as expected the problem was another jQuery that was implementing a higher height on the site. Again, sorry.